# Acceso al operador {{ }} de forma anidada en Laravel Blade Template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en `Laravel`, donde tengo una etiqueta `a`en `html5`, a la cuál a través del atributo `href` quiero acceder a una url dentro de la aplicación de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="{{ url('app/alguna/ruta/{{$primerId}}/otraruta/{{$segundoId}}') }}"
```

pero estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'

El problema de esto es que estoy llamando de forma anidada al operador `{{ }}` para acceder a la variables que fueron enviadas por el controlador en el template. **¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que {{ }} no es más que un wrapper de un echo php, por lo cual funciona como php regular:

```
<a href="{{ url('app/alguna/ruta/' . $primerId . '/otraruta/' . $segundoId) }}">
```

Comment: Gracias!!! esto funciono

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas colocando llaves de mas `{{}}`, ya que funcionan como un echo de php.

```
<a href="{{ url('app/alguna/ruta/{{$primerId}}/otraruta/{{$segundoId}}') }}">
```

No necesitas volver a colocar llaves para imprimir una variable

```
<a href="{{ url('app/alguna/ruta/' . $primerId . '/otraruta/' . $segundoId') }}">
```

Cuando sea una ruta de tipo `{{ url('app/alguna/ruta/' . $primerId') }}` podrías colocarlo así `{{ url('app/alguna/ruta', [$primerId]) }}`